# R Markdown Error: 'is_latex_output' is not an exported object from 'namespace:knitr'

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have this Error when I first time using R Markdown, just a simple test run.

````
---
title: "test"
author: "Lulu"
date: "3/6/2018"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(datasets)
data("airquality")
summary(airquality)
```
````

then it reports:

```
output file: test.knit.md

Error: 'is_latex_output' is not an exported object from 'namespace:knitr'
Execution halted
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 9):

Not the most current version

You can try update Knitr

```
install.packages('knitr', repos = c('http://rforge.net', 'http://cran.rstudio.org'),
             type = 'source')
```